# What would you do instead of using NSViewController to be compatible with 10.4?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsviewcontroller

All I need to do is load and swap some nibs in a NSView of a window. I know how to do it with NSViewController and have it working perfectly with 10.5-10.6, but I don't know what to do for 10.4.

Tutorial links very welcome, I have trouble finding legacy stuff.

(Yes, I really do need to support 10.4.)

Comment: (Yes, I really do need to support 10.4.)… Are you sure? Really? Stats have repeatedly proven that consumers that don't update their OS don't update their app's ether. The only notable exception is K-12.

Comment: I'm really, really sure. This release we're finally dropping 10.3(!). Next release we're going to drop 10.4. (My app is supplemental to the main app.) The main app has to be updated every four months or it stops working. (You subscribe yearly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From working with `NSViewController` in Leopard, I can tell you that its functionality is very basic, and that you should be able to replicate it with fairly minimal effort.

Essentially, it has a `view` property/outlet, and an `initWithNibName:bundle:` method. Beyond that, it doesn't do anything especially fancy. It has some convenience things, like adopting `NSEditor`, and a `representedObject` property. You should be able to bang out an equivalent class in an hour or two.

Now, what you will give up if you do this is compatibility with later versions of Cocoa. Eventually, you'll probably drop 10.4 support and you'll be left with your class and the real `NSViewController`. When that happens, I'd recommend re-basing your custom view controller on Cocoa's `NSViewController`. If you've named the properties with the same names/data types as `NSViewController`, you should only have to drop the properties and methods you've declared yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NSBundle`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/loadNibNamed:owner:) to load the nib:

```
YourController *controller = [[YourController alloc] init];
BOOL success = [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"YourNibName" owner:controller];
```

Comment: Looks like loadNibName:owner is a class method, not an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you write your own controller class that does the same things that NSViewController does.  The controller classes were added to the AppKit because so many of us were writing essentially the same code over and over.

Comment: I was told there is one out there on one of the Cocoa dev sites, but I couldn't find it...